# ASP.NET Javascript Error :: sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ASP.NET site that uses JQuery and ASP.NET UpdatePanel and ScriptManager.  On one page in particular, I get a javascript error:

```
sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception: Index and length must refer to a  location within the string.  Parameter name:length
```

ScriptResourse.axd
Code: 0

Edit:
This error does not occur in my development environment, only when I publish the code to the test server.

Here's what's in the master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptMgr"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelMaster">
    <ContentTemplate>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the page in question:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentHeadEdit" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHeadMaster" Runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%= ButtonSave.ClientID %>').button();

        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            $('#<%= ButtonSave.ClientID %>').button();
        }
    });
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in the server-side code. If you run debug (breaking on errors), you should get your line number. Alternatively, you could scan through your code-behind for a line of code that uses and `index` and `length` parameter. It looks like some sort of string manipulation call, and the value of `length` is either negative or larger than the length of the string you're working on.

Comment: I've updated the post, but this error does not occur in my development environment, only when I publish the code to the test server.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this very same issue and finally solved it by removing all the AJAX controls until i had a basic form with no UpdatePanel (this hides the true server side error that is going on). Turns out then the error was pure c# issue in the code behind.

Comment: this saved me, I have been breaking my head on this issue for a while and doing so pointed me right in the problem on the code behind. Thanks